# how to block pop ups in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, blocking, google-chrome-extensions, adblock

I am using Chrome on a Ubuntu system and using Chrome a website has been highly irritating 
http://www.snapdeal.com/daily-deal-alert-subscription-OMG?utm_source=uranus&utm_campaign=l&utm_content=LP4&utm_medium=ImageStatic

regularly opens its pop ups is there a way I can block the above link on Chrome or pop ups which are randomly coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the [Adblock Plus extension](https://adblockplus.org/en/chrome) should solve your problem. I am running Chrome with this extension and the URL you provided gave me no problems.

The easiest way to install it is:
1) Google Adblock Plus Chrome.
2) Click the first result.
3) Click the Install button and in a few seconds you'll be good to go!

@D